# Kubernetes: running pods amount does not match with the desired state

Tags: kubernetes

```
(base) ➜  code kubectl get pods -n my_namespace                                    
NAME                           AGE
app-service-5b587bc8c7-vxkk4   7d16h
app-service-5b587bc8c7-vxn4n   6d8h
```

```
(base) ➜  code kubectl get rs -n my_namespace                                                                   
NAME                     AGE
app-service-5b587bc8c7   7d16h
```

```
(base) ➜  code kubectl describe rs/app-service-5b587bc8c7 -n my_namespace

Controlled By:  Deployment/app-service
Replicas:       3 current / 3 desired
Pods Status:    2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

```
(base) ➜  code kubectl get event -n my_namespace
NAME                                                 AGE
app-service-custom-hpa.175ba564f2214ae2   2d1h
```

Why is there a mismatch between running and desired?
Also, why is there 3 current if kubectl reports only 2 pods?

Comment: Probably there is something to be fixed in the Replicaset or Horizontal Pod Autoscaling. Can you add them?

Comment: Check `kubectl get event` for events related to scheduling.

Comment: I can imagine causes like "the cluster is at capacity, can't schedule another pod, and can't allocate another node", or "you are trying to share a ReadWriteOnce volume but the only node that can access it is full", or "the namespace has a resource quota".

Answer (score 0):

This information that I posted above was retrieved via the Periscope shell script, and I was informed that the Periscope itself was having some issues that caused stale/incomplete data returned.